# A moderate introduction to Hanbury Brown Twiss interferometry in particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-optics, interferometry

For astronomy, as originally invented, the [Hanbury Brown Twiss interferometer](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=hanbury+brown+twiss+interferometer) is good for finding the angular diameter of stars and is not a rapidly fluctuating observable like the amplitude in ordinary interferometry. The same concept in particle physics is not so straightforward. When I measure the 2 particle correlation, what do I get? What does it mean?

Comment: I know its use in astronomy fairly well.  The application to particle physics relies on the bunching effect of bosons.  'The Intensity Interferometer by Hanbury Brown has a chapter on coincidence counting of photons.  This is closely related to bunching of particles.

Comment: A nice review on the subject: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.08239

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about size, shape and rotation of the emitting object.
I would start here: http://cds.cern.ch/record/378753/files/9902020.pdf